# Can every linear grammar be converted to Greibach form?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

Can every [linear grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar) be converted to a linear [Greibach normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greibach_normal_form), a form in which all productions look like $A \rightarrow ax$ where $a \in T$ and $x \in V \cup \{\lambda\}$?

($T$ is the set of terminals, $V$ is the set of non-terminals, $\lambda$ is the empty sequence.)

Comment: Yes, it is one of the “normal forms”. But there may be an issue with left recursion, have to check.

Comment: Your notation isn't entirely clear to me. Is $T$ the set of terminals and $V$ the non-terminals, or $V$ the vocabulary and $T$ the rules?

Comment: Every grammar can be converted to a GNF, but the GNF is more general than your definition. I've edited your question to define the notations, please check that this is what you meant.

Comment: Note that linear grammars that are restricted to the form you propose, $A\to aB$ or $A\to a$ are so-called right-linear grammars, and generate exactly the regular languages. This means that the linear language $\{a^nb^n\mid n\ge 1\}$ cannot be generated by a grammar which is both linear and in Greibach normal form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The more general answer is:

[Blum and Koch](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.47.460) showed a polynomial time transformation such that any context-free grammar can be converted to [Greibach form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greibach_normal_form).

Since a [linear grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar) is a special case of Context-free grammar, the answer is yes.

---

EDIT: the rest of this answer is out of scope since the question was about Linear GNF and not just GNF (thanks @hendrik-jan for spotting this)

A simpler transformation:

- Any rule $X \rightarrow a_1 a_2 \cdot a_k Y$ you transform them in $k$ rules:

  1. $X\rightarrow a_1 X_1Y$.
  2. $\cdots$
  3. $X_{i-1}\rightarrow a_{i}X_i$
  4. $X_{k-1}\rightarrow a_{k}Y$
- Any rule $X \rightarrow a Y b$ should be transformed in two rules

  1. $X \rightarrow a Y Y_1$.
  2. $Y_1 \rightarrow b$

where the capital letters belong to $V$ and the small letters to the alphabet (terminals).

Comment: The simpler transformation proposed here does not take into account productions that are left-recursive, i.e., of the form $A\to Ba$. Also, the second case does introduce a rule $X\to aYY_1$, which is not linear.

Comment: True, missing $A\rightarrow Ba$: you can transform in $A\rightarrow B \tilde{A}$ and $\tilde{A}\rightarrow a$.

As for $X \rightarrow a YY_1$, it is not meant to be linear but GNF

Comment: Thanks for reacting, even for such an old question. What I mean is: the result is GNF, but not necessarily in "linear GNF", as specified in the question.

Comment: True, it seems that I missed this! (and so did the author of the question at the time it seems!)

Comment: Now I'm not even sure the beginning is correct (update: actually given your comment it probably isn't)